# Xcode 10 warning "unexpected C compiler invocation with specified output"

Tags: objective-c, xcode10, swift4.2

I have a project with both Swift and Objective-C code.

After upgrading to Xcode 10 and Swift 4.2, I get the following warning for two of my objective-C .m files:

> :-1: unexpected C compiler invocation with specified output:
>   '/Users/[username]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[filepath]'
>   (for input: '/Users/[username]/Documents/Projects/[filepath]') (in
>   target [targetName])

How can I debug this?

Comment: If you revert to the Legacy Build System does that solve it?

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. Actually yeah the warnings go away when I use the legacy build system. Hmm does that mean it's a bug with the new build system? And that there is no way to get rid of it? I have already tried to clean and delete derived folder.

Comment: Whenever I see `DerivedData` in an error, and sometimes if I don't, I go to `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` and clear it's contents. It works more often than not.

Comment: I've started getting this issue with Xcode 12 and it's driving me insane.  I have 3 Obj C files that are showing up as Resource Files in my package, but I don't have them in the Copy Bundle Resources section.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured out the issue:
I have some of my source files accidentally listed under "Copy Bundle Resources" in Build Phases.
Fixed by removing those files from "Copy Bundle Resources".

Comment: i am getting the same warning. i have core data model, xibs and storyboards listed there. and also Assets.xcassets. can any of these be a problem?